# React Native RNDateTimePicker : Unable to select date

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am a complete beginner in react native. I have used RNDateTimePicker for date picker and the calendar is shown with current date as default. But when I try to select other dates it seems like clicked but I am not getting any log on onChange. Also the selected date is not highlighted and current date is highlighted instead. Once OK button is pressed initial date ie; today's date is obtained on onChange.

Searched for a solution. But none of them solved the issue. Here is my code. Any help would be grateful.

Updates : This issue is only found on Nougat version.

```
   import React, {useState, useContext} from 'react';
   import {View, Text, TouchableOpacity,} from 'react-native';
   import RNDateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';
   const UiTest = (props) => {
   const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
   const [show, setShow] = useState(true);

   return (
 <View>
  <Text> Test components </Text>
  <RNDateTimePicker
    mode="date"
    value={date}
    maximumDate={new Date()}
    minimumDate={new Date(2020, 10, 1)}
    onChange={(event, value) => {
      console.log('Selected-----------'+value);
      setDate(value);
    }}
  />
 
</View>
);};
export default UiTest;
```

Comment: The params from the `onChange` (written in the documentation) are `(event, date)`. Replace `value` with `date` and give it a try

Comment: @dianaqqq tried . but no change

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce the error, it works for me with the code you provided.

onChange gets called only after you press OK on the picker dialog.

If the date keeps resetting to today, maybe there is some other code updating the state in the background and making a re-render.

I can see the logs normally. They are located in the Metro bundler window. You can also view logs by calling these in new terminal window:

`npx react-native log-android` or
`npx react-native log-ios`

Comment: I have an update. This issue is only found on nougat os. On the other devices it works fine